# The category with binary relations as objects

Tags: category-theory, relations

I have reconsidered my ideas and remember how I thought ones upon a time. I will make a last try and delete if it doesn't work:

**Set** is the category where sets are objects and functions are morphisms and
**Rel** is the category where sets are objects and binary relations are morphisms.

I can think about two categories where *functions* are the objects, with pair of functions $(\alpha,\beta)$
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>\alpha>> X'\\
@VfV V @VVf'V\\
Y @>>\beta> Y'
\end{CD}
as morphism, with or without a condition of commutative diagrams ($f'\alpha=\beta f$). For relations these alternative do not preserve even the structure of relations as graphs in a natural way.
$$
\begin{CD}
X @>\alpha>> X'\\
@VR V\qquad \displaystyle ? V @VVR'V\\
Y @>>\beta> Y'
\end{CD}
$$
Is there a suitable condition on the diagram that preserves the graph-structure and make the pairs of relations $(\alpha,\beta)$ to morphisms?

---

The composition of relations $\alpha\subset X\times X'$ and $\alpha'\subset X'\times X''$ is defined

$(x,x'')\in\alpha'\alpha \Leftrightarrow \exists x'\in X':(x,x')\in\alpha \wedge (x',x'')\in \alpha'$.

---

You where right about my first attempt, but I hope that this is interesting enought, since many structures in mathematics in fact is just relations, and preserving those relation should be interesting.

Comment: I don't understand your question. e.g. I don't see why you think there is a problem defining the category of binary relations and commutative squares of relations. Your construction would appear to work on *any category at all*, and has nothing to do with whether the morphisms from the original category are functions or relations or even a completely abstract thing.

Comment: to second @Hurkyl 's comment: For any category you can construct the category of arrows of it. The objects are the morphisms and the morphisms are pairs of morphisms as making a commutative square as you describe. This works for Rel as well.

Comment: I don't think that you can prove that. Of course it holds for all categories, but with relations as objects and commuting pairs as *candidates* to morphisms, the composition don't have to be of the right sort.

Comment: if it works for any category, why should it not work for Rel???

Comment: Maybe there exists an composition of relations that works, but the ordinary doesn't. You must admit that the definition of the composition interfere.

Comment: If the ordinary composition of relation turns Rel into a category (which it does), then the construction works ... Even if you want functions for horizontal and relations for vertical arrows, this doesn't really matter as the composition for functions *is* the composition for relations

Comment: Confusing to be wrong in such an easy question! I will reformulate the question or delete it.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at http://www2.math.uu.se/~mazor/PREPRINTS/PAUL/binary.pdf

Comment: First, thank you all, for your patience with my ignorance, delusions and laziness. And thanks @ John Smith: for the pdf (from my own university a long, long time ago. I will check it out even if it seems to be to depth for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Hurkyl* + *Ittay Weiss* are right)

If u define **Rel** to have sets as objects and binary relations as arrows and you show this makes it a category, then u have (as for any category):

---

Say $\mathcal{C}$ is an arbitrary category (not necessarily small)

Define $\mathcal{\hat C}$ to be the category having as objects all $\mathcal{C}$-arrows and as arrows between two $\mathcal{\hat C}$-objects $f:A\longrightarrow A'$, $g:B\longrightarrow B'$ the pairs of $\mathcal C$-arrows $\phi_{AB}:A\longrightarrow B$, $\phi_{A'B'}:A'\longrightarrow B'$ such that the following diagram commutes

\begin{align}
A & \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\longrightarrow & B\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
A' & \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\longrightarrow &B'
\end{align}

The composition of arrows is well defined since for $\mathcal{\hat C}$-objects $f:A\longrightarrow A'$, $g:B\longrightarrow B'$ and $h:C\longrightarrow C'$ and $\mathcal{\hat C}$-arrows (i.e. commuting $\mathcal{C}$-diagrams)

\begin{align}
A & \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\longrightarrow & B\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
A' & \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\longrightarrow &B'
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
B & \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\longrightarrow & C \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
B' & \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\longrightarrow &C'
\end{align}

the combined $\mathcal{C}$-diagram commutes

\begin{align}
A & \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\longrightarrow & B & \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\longrightarrow & C \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
A' & \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\longrightarrow &B' & \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\longrightarrow &C'
\end{align}

thus buidling a composed $\mathcal{\hat C}$-arrow $\phi_{AC}:A\longrightarrow C$, $\phi_{A'C'}:A'\longrightarrow C'$